# Navigating with Nuxt Middleware does not run on all pages because adminUser is null

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3

I have 3 simple pages in my application. A Login page, a Search page and Results page.. Only admins are allowed to search. In order to determine if a user is allowed to search, they enter their username and password. I also have a composable called useAdmin
That gets sent to a backend service which sends the user information with the admin status if that individual is an admin. Therefore, the admin user object in my ref is null. I have included the code that retrieves the admin info. The problem is that my middleware is only being triggered only once and since the admin user is null at the start, the navigation does not go to the search page. Here is the composable useAdmin below. The index.vue is the Login page.

```js
             // Composable useAdmin
             import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios"

                interface LogonRequest {
                username: string ,
                password?: string 
                }

                interface SearchRequest{
                    //....
                }
                interface SearchResponse{
                    //....
                }

                const adminUser: Ref<AdminUser | null> = ref(null)

                interface AdminUser {
                
                   username: string ,
                   isAdmin: boolean, 
                   role: string
                }

                export default function () {
                    
                const search = async (url: string, search: SearchRequest): Promise<SearchResponse> => {      
                        const {data, status} = await axios.post(url,  search) 
                        return {
                            data: data,
                            status: status
                            }     
                    }
                
                async function login( url: string, logonRequest:LogonRequest): Promise<AdminUser> {
                    const {data, status} = await axios.post(url,logonRequest)
                    adminUser.value = data
                    return adminUser
                }
                return {
                    login,
                    search,
                    adminUser,
                    
                   }
                }
```

Here is my middleware code:

```js
               export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
                    //adminUser is null initially but is not after login
                    const adminUser = useAdmin()
                    if (to.path !== '/search'  && adminUser.value.role === 'ADMIN') {
                      return navigateTo('/search')
                    }
               })
```

How can I get it to navigate to the search?